# 720p signal from Mac Mini isn't centered on TV?

Tags: macos, hdmi, tv, media-center, mac-mini

I have a Mac Mini as my media center machine, and it's outputing 720p over a DVI to HDMI cable, to my TV. The image is vertically centered, but it's shifted to the left almost completely.

Is there anything I can do to fix this easily, or am I stuck because the TV is crappy (it's a Haier). My Xbox 360 has no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Mac Mini is configured the same way like yours except the TV is a Sony Bravia. I guess it's most likely you need to adjust your TV settings. Sorry can't help you more because I don't have same kind of TV.

Comment: Unfortunately, the TV is cheap enough that it doesn't have any settings over HDMI.

Answer (score 1):

I've hit the exact issue hooking my Macbook up to my Samsung HDTV. I believe the issue is connected to the refresh rate. You also might want to play around with the overscan setting.

I've read that this propriety program, [SwiResX](http://www.madrau.com/SRX3/html/SRX/DL.shtml), is suppose to solve the issue (though apparently it has issues with 10.5, which makes it useless on any modern Mac).

Here is a discussion thread on the topic

> [Howto get 1080p on SAMSUNG LCD TV](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1639648&tstart=30)

Comment: I'd actually tried that software and it made a mess of things. Overscan doesn't seem to work either, pushing everything off screen.

Comment: Oh that is too bad about that software. For the overscan thing, I was more mentioning it in combination with different refresh rates it may get results, kind of moot if you can't mess with the refresh rate. Hopefully someone out there in superuser land can help you more, because I would like a solution too.